# How do I create a Hash from an Array using the Prototype JavaScript framewor?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I've an Array `['red', 'green', 'blue']`

I want to create a new Hash from this Array, the result should be

```
{'red':true, 'green':true, 'blue':true}
```

What is the best way to achieve that goal using Prototype?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just iterate over the array and then create the Hash:

```
var obj  = {};
for(var i = 0, l = colors.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[colors[i]] = true;
}
var hash = new Hash(obj);
```

You can also create a new Hash object from the beginning:

```
var hash = new Hash();
for(var i = 0, l = colors.length; i < l; i++) {
    hash.set(colors[i], true);
}
```

I suggest to have a look at the [**documentation**](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Hash/).

Comment: Apart from primitives, like strings, numbers, booleans, etc.

Comment: @Marcel: I am not quite sure how these are handled internally but I think they are objects too.

Comment: I'm also not sure how JS engines handle those internally, but strings, numbers and booleans are definitely not objects according to the [ECMAScript specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_8.htm#Section_8). E.g., when using `String` methods, a string primitive is temporarily converted to an object, the method is called and the `String` object is converted back to a string primitive. Also notice that all objects should evaluate to `true`, whereas primitives can evaluate to `false`. E.g.: `var yes = new Boolean(false); if (yes) alert("I <3 JavaScript");` outputs `I <3 JavaScript`

Comment: Prototype includes a special object called a Hash.

Answer (score 11):

This functional javascript solution uses [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
['red', 'green', 'blue']
.reduce((hash, elem) => { hash[elem] = true; return hash }, {})
```

[Parameter Details](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_reduce.htm):

- callback − Function to execute on each value in the array.
- initialValue − Object to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback.

The third argument to the callback is the index of the current element being processed in the array. So if you wanted to create a lookup table of elements to their index:

```
['red', 'green', 'blue'].reduce(
  (hash, elem, index) => {
    hash[elem] = index++;
    return hash
  }, {});
```

Returns:

```
Object {red: 0, green: 1, blue: 2}
```

Comment: If this isn't working for you make sure you didn't forget the last parameter-- `, {}`. Without it you get just the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all

here is my solution using `prototypejs` and inspired by Felix's answer

```
var hash = new Hash();
colors.each(function(color) {
  hash.set(color, true);
});
```